# ASP.NET SQL Configuration

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, authentication, passwords

I created an ASP.NET Website with "Individual user accounts" authentication. I want to know how I can modify the SQL Database that stores the user info so I can change the minimum amount of characters needed to create a password on my web site. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-web-app-with-email-confirmation-and-password-reset

If you look closely to the database table, you will notice the `PasswordHash` and you will also notice that there is no password field.

That is because we don't store passwords in databases. Since the password is not there, you can't apply rules to it.

You must implement the checks, serverside instead of database, just before registration.

Comment: "Data connections" in server explorer is empty. Is this normal?